# ¿como tomar los valores de un arreglo que esta definido a traves del atrbuto name[] en php?

Tags: post

me encuentro en un problema que no he podido resolver, me gustaría poder contar con su ayuda... El problema que se me esta ocasionando se debe a que no puedo procesar los valores que han sido ingresado en los inputs de mi formulario al php. Este formulario es dinámico, ya que el usuario puede agregar o quitar los campos que requiera, para ello tengo un script, donde las funciones son invocadas a través del boton onclick. Por otro lado, tengo el HTML y un input con el atributo name[], lo que significa que este atributo es identificado como un arreglo. Es decir, aquí se almacenarán todos los datos que el usuario escriba.. PERO NO SE COMO PROCESAR ESOS DATOS AL PHP, y or ende a mi base de datos... Les omparto mi código que  tengo hasta ahorita..

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">


        <link rel = "stylesheet"  href = "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" > <!--- bootstrap del cdn del form  ----> 
        <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
        <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!---  jqury permite despligr y editar elform----> 





        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Encuesta/IconsFontAwesome/css/all.min.css">  <!--- Librería Font Awesome----> 
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Encuesta/Estilos/preguntas113.css">
        <script src="../Encuesta/JavaScript/Eventos.js"></script>




        <!------ Include the above in your HEAD tag ---------->
    </head>




    <body>
  <?php
        include ('../Administradores/Conexion.php');

        if (!empty($_POST ['btnEnviar'])) {

            $insertarP = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, ['InsertarPregunta']);

            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO preguntas_inmujer (Pregunta) VALUES ('$insertarP')");

            /* Comprueba la conexión */
            if ($mysqli->error) {
                echo "error" . $mysqli->error;

                /*  */
            } else {


                /* aquí va el script */
                ?>            


                <?php
            }
        }

        /* Cierra la conexión */
        $mysqli->close();
        ?>






        <br>
        <form class="form" method="post" action="Preguntas.php" onsubmit="">
            <div  class="container register-form" id=""  >
                <div class="form">
                    <div class="note">
                        <!------ Aquí va los campos de texto de nombre del formulario----------> 
                    </div>


                    <!------  elemento que quiero que se duplique   ----------> 
                    <div action="preguntas.php" class="form-content" id="addAnswer"  onsubmit="return ok();"  >
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12" id="EliminarCuadrito" onclick="eliminar(this)"> <!------ los ID estan siendo llamados en javaScript ----------> 
                                <div class="form-group" id="EliminarCuadro"> 
                                    <br> <input id="pregunta" type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe su pregunta" required >
                                </div>

                                <!------    pie de pagina del contenedor ----------> 
                                <div class="card-footer text-muted" id="RemoveBoton">
                                    <button onclick="eliminar();" id="botonEliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary"><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button> <br>
                                </div>
                                <!------  aquí estamos mandando llamar el contenido que desearemos almacenar dentro del div  ----------> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!------   fin del elemento que quiero que se duplique   ----------> 
                    </div>
                </div>
                <button id="generarEncuesta" name="btnEnviar" type="submit" value="RalizarEncuesta" class="btnSubmit" >Generar Encuesta</button>
                <button id="add" name="GuardaPregunta" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" onclick="agregar();"> <i class="fas fa-plus"></i> Añadir pregunta</button>
            </div>
   </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

```
// Estoy mandando llamar a la función agregar que tiene el boton con el evento onclick
function agregar(){
$('#addAnswer').append('<div> <input id="pregunta" type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Escribe su pregunta" required > \n\
<button onclick="eliminar(this)" id="botonEliminar" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" class="card-footer text-muted" ><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></button> <br><br></div>')
}

function eliminar(EliminarCuadrito){
    $(EliminarCuadrito).closest('div').remove();
}
```

**Inserción**

```
       <?php
        include '../Administradores/Conexion.php';


        /* if empty es una validación de función del php--- empty evalua si el dato fue posteado y guardado en una variable  */
        $valor = !empty($_POST['InsertarPregunta']) ? $_POST['InsertarPregunta'] : NULL; /* la variable valor es la que recupera los valores que se escribieron en la variable name: InsertarPregunta */
        var_dump($valor);  /* var_dump me sirve para imprimir la información que trae la variable valor */

        $sql = "INSERT INTO preguntas_inmujer (Pregunta) VALUES (?)";  /* Esta pendiente, ya que debo de convertir el array en cadena */
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $questions);

        $mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
        foreach ($valor as $question) {
            $stmt->execute();
        }
        $stmt->close();
        $mysqli->query("COMMIT");
        ?>
```

Estuve tratando de realizar este proceso de inserción que me menciono, pero al ejecutarlo me muestra este error :(
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp1\htdocs\MUJER03\Encuesta\Preguntas.php on line 45
 este error esta sucediendo en el foreach ahí tiene dos variables, una es la que ya trae los valores del arreglo, pero la otra no se que?. ;(  ¿porque esta pasando esto?.. porque sabe, tambien cuando ingreso datos en los inputs, no me esta guardando nada en la base de datos. :/

Answer (score 0):

Ten en cuenta que `$_POST` y `$_GET` crean un array para guardar los datos. En dicho array la clave es lo que haya en la etiqueta `name` de cada elemento y el valor es el dato que se haya escrito en el `input`.

Supongamos que tienes esto:

```
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
```

Y en cada uno de los input escribes: `Pregunta 1`, `Pregunta 2`, `Pregunta 3`...

Si el método del formulario es `POST`, podrías recoger los datos como se hace con cualquier otro elemento, mediante un `$_POST['InsertarPregunta']`.

Una técnica que me gusta usar es evaluar mediante `empty` si el dato fue posteado y guardarlo en una variable. Luego, uso esa variable para sacar los datos.

```
$mQuestions=!empty($_POST['InsertarPregunta']) ? $_POST['InsertarPregunta'] : NULL;
```

Aquí, si los datos fueron posteados, `$mQuestions` será un array con esos datos. Si hacemos un `var_dump($mQuestions)` veremos esto:

```
array(3) { 
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Pregunta 1"
  [1]=>
  string(10) "Pregunta 2"
  [2]=>
  string(10) "Pregunta 3"
}
```

Para sacar las preguntas, puedes usar un `foreach` o acceder directamente por los índices:

```
foreach ($mQuestions as $question) {
    echo $question.PHP_EOL;
}
```

O, para la pregunta 1 por ejemplo, sin `foreach`:

```
echo $mQuestions[0];
```

Imaginemos que hay que trabajar con preguntas y respuestas. Los inputs quedarían así:

```
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarRespuesta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarRespuesta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarPregunta[]">
    <input type="text" name="InsertarRespuesta[]">
```

Si mandas cada pregunta con su respectiva respuesta, se puede hacer una lectura interesante en la cual, partiendo de la pregunta, se busca el texto de la misma, y luego, se usa el índice de cada pregunta para buscar la respuesta en el array de respuestas:

```
$mQuestions=!empty($_POST['InsertarPregunta']) ? $_POST['InsertarPregunta'] : NULL;
$mAnswers=!empty($_POST['InsertarRespuesta']) ? $_POST['InsertarRespuesta'] : NULL;
foreach ($mQuestions as $k=>$question){
    echo "P: $question \tA: $mAnswers[$k]".PHP_EOL; 

}
```

**Salida:**

```
P: Pregunta 1   A: Respuesta 1
P: Pregunta 2   A: Respuesta 2
P: Pregunta 3   A: Respuesta 3
```

---

### Insertar en la base de datos

Si `$mQuestions` es un array con todas las preguntas, podrías efectuar una inserción de cada pregunta mediante este código:

```
#Aquí $mQuestions representa el array de preguntas que fueron pasadas desde el form
$sql="INSERT INTO preguntas_inmujer (Pregunta) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt ->bind_param("s", $question);

$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
foreach ($mQuestions as $question) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

Aquí se usa la práctica conocida como *consultas preparadas*, que consiste en preparar la consulta con un marcador `?` y pasar los datos más adelante. Esto evita ataques de inyección SQL y para este caso agiliza bastante el código, porque el plan de consulta se prepara una sola vez.

Se usa también transacciones. Si hay algún fallo se revierten todas las inserciones, para que no queden datos dispares insertados. O se insertan todas las preguntas o no se inserta ninguna. Así, no tienes que ir viendo luego qué preguntas se insertaron o cuales no.

Comment: hola! muchas gracias por responder a mi pregunta. lo que usted me menciona a un principio lo entiendo perfectamente,  ya que mediante un $_POST['InsertarPregunta']. se recogen los valores que fueron escritos por el usuario, pero el problema es, que no se como proceder a insertar esos datos en la base de datos mysql. haciendo el uso de la sentencia INSERT INTOP reguntas_inmujer (Pregunta) VALUES ('$insertarP')");. pregunto porque como mencione  también, el formulario es dinámico, debido a que se pueden insertar y eliminar inputs, esto se encuentra el archivo js.

Comment: @XIMENA revisa la respuesta, la he editado, agregando al final un apartado donde explico cómo insertar los datos de una forma segura y más optimizada.

Comment: agradezco que me este ayudando con este proceso, esto para mi es algo nuevo, pues comienzo a relacionarme con lo nuevo de páginas web. con respecto a lo de la inserción me surgieron algunas dudas, las cuales necesito que me diga si estoy bien o mal. 'Verdad que todos las palabras que están nombradas con un "$" al inicio,  son variables que ha ido creando?.. Pues como verá trate de hacer este segundo paso que me reafirmo con respecto a la inserción, pero me esta dando un error en el for each.

Comment: @XIMENA correcto, en PHP cuando hay un `$` delante es para indicar una variable u objeto.

Comment: @XIMENA he rechazado la edición de la respuesta por este motivo: *Esta edición tenía como objetivo dirigirse al autor de la publicación y no tiene sentido como una edición. Se debería haber escrito como un comentario o una respuesta.* Stackoverflow no es un foro, si luego de la corrección hay algún error, debes indicarlo en un comentario, no editando la respuesta. Por favor, indica el error que te da en u comentario. Gracias.