# PHP- Pasar un array por un value de un checkbox dinamico

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de pasar 4 variables  por un **checkbox**, lo que pensé es hacer un arreglo y ahí pasar las variables que necesito, entonces lo que tengo es un **checkbox dinamico** que funciona correctamente, en el campo `value` del **checkbox** mando el array como `serialize` y al momento de recogerlo en el otro php lo recibo con `unserialize` pero no me muestra nada, no sé si algo estoy haciendo mal

Les muestro mi código:

```
<form name="frmNotification" id="frmNotification" action="php/agregarnotificacion.php" method="post">
  <?php
  while ($fila3 = $mostrarSeguidores->fetch_assoc()) {

     $array = [
      'id_s' => $_SESSION['idusr'],
      'ti_s' => $_SESSION['tipo'],
      'id_r' => $_SESSION['rediccionaridPerfilInm'],
      'ti_r' => $_SESSION['rediccionartipoPerfilInm']
      ];
  if($fila3['us_tipo']==1) // Usuario normal
      {                                    
      ?>
  <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo serialize($array); ?> "><label for="checkbox1"><a class="enlaceperfil" href="perfil.php?var=<?php echo $fila3['se_idSeguidor'];?>&tipo_usuS=<?php echo $fila3['se_tipoSeguidor'];?>&username=<?php echo $nombre_Usuario;?>&id_usu=<?php echo $_SESSION['idusr'];?>&tipo_usu=<?php echo $_SESSION['tipo'];?>"><div class="circular--portraittRecomendar"><img src="<?php echo $fila3['us_ruta_perfil']; ?>"></div><?php echo $fila3['us_nickname'];?></a></label>                  
  <br><br>
  <?php 
  } else if($fila3['us_tipo']==2) // Usuario empleado
  {
  ?>
  <input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo serialize($array); ?> "><label for="checkbox2"><a class="enlaceperfil" href="perfil.php?var=<?php echo $fila3['se_idSeguidor'];?>&tipo_usuS=<?php echo $fila3['se_tipoSeguidor'];?>&username=<?php echo $nombre_Usuario;?>&id_usu=<?php echo $_SESSION['idusr'];?>&tipo_usu=<?php echo $_SESSION['tipo'];?>"><div class="circular--portraittRecomendar"><img src="<?php echo $fila3['us_ruta_perfil']; ?>"></div><?php echo $fila3['us_nombre_completo'];?></a></label>                
 <br><br>
  <?php 
  }  ...
```

Y en el otro archivo lo recibo así:

```
 $miArray = unserialize($_POST["checkbox"]);
 echo $miArray;
```

Al final del día quiero recibir esas 4 variables y guardarlas en la base de datos.

Comment: ¿Por qué usas `unserialize`? ¿Podrías mostrarnos lo que imprime un `var_dump($_POST["checkbox"]);`? Ya en `$_POST["checkbox"]` deberías tener un array si todo se envía correctamente.

Comment: utilize el serilize y unserialize, por lo que entendi con ese me ayudaria a pasar el array por el checkbox,

Comment: imrpimi el  var_dump($_POST["checkbox"]); y me muestra esto :                                  array(1) { [0]=> string(9) "a:4:{s:4:" }

Comment: Me parece que usar aquí `serialize` y `unserialize` lo que hace es complicar las cosas. Prueba a omitir su uso, o sea, **no uses `serialize` cuando creas los checkbox, ni uses `unserialize` cuando recibes el POST** y recibirás un array natural en `$_POST["checkbox"]` que es lo que necesitas, si he entendido bien.

Comment: Ok perfecto, lo modificare entonces

Comment: Ya lo probe asi normal pase el array pero solo me imprime esto: array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "Array " }      , nose si estoy bn pero estaba pensando pasar los valores por value y concatenar las 4 variables que necesito, nose si sea viable

Comment: Creo que tienes un problema contextual que no has explicado bien. Por ejemplo, yo veo un uso de `fetch_assoc()` que supondría que estás leyendo datos de una base de datos, pero luego veo que usas variables de sesión. ¿Podrías explicarnos un poco más claro que es lo que quieres hacer realmente para poder ayudarte mejor?

Comment: mIra lo que quiero hacer es como un  recomendar como facebook cuando recomiendas una pagina a alguien, para esto los usuarios que muestro son los del checkbox dinamico y para eso jalo de mi mismo archivo las variables de sesion de la persona que esta logueada(que jalo el id y tipo),tambien jalo el id y el tipo del recomendado y me faltan otras 2 varialbes id y tipo de quienes les voy a recomendar, nose si me explique

Comment: No entiendo mucho. ¿Por qué mezclas variables de sesión dentro de un `while` que lee datos de la base de datos? En cualquier caso, si pones varios inputs así: `name="checkbox[]"` con valores diferentes, luego vas a tener en `$_POST["checkbox"]` un array con esos valores. ¿No es eso lo que quieres? [Mira los ejemplos de esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/305410/29967)

Answer (score 2):

Dependiendo de cuan confidencial sean los datos que quieres transmitir, otra forma puede ser utilizando un formato de `JSON`. Entonces al generar tu `HTML` puedes hacer algo como:

```
<input name="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo json_encode($array); ?>">
```

y luego cuando recibes el `POST` puedes hacer algo como:

```
$miArray = json_decode($_POST["checkbox"], true);
```

y claro que a este código le faltan validaciones para que tu código sea seguro y evites posibles problemas con los **"undefined indexes"**.

Comment: Lo voy a probar asi

Comment: Al momento de recorrerlo por un foreach me arroja NULL

Comment: una cuestion que tienes que tener en cuenta, en mi codigo no estoy utilizando checkbox[] como nombre del input, si tu lo utilizas tienes que hacer el codigo necesario:

`foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $value){
    $miArray = json_decode(value, true);
}`

Tambien puedes probar si le haces un `var_dump($_POST)` y muestranos que te sale.

Comment: Si lo considere de echo me di chuenta del nombre del input, pero no me imprime nada

Answer (score 1):

que tal si intentas recorrer con un `for` la variable POST que usas ya que esta viene como array con 4 posiciones de 0 a 3 y en cada posición tienes los arrays serializados que buscas. Es decir:

```
$data = []
Foreach($_POST['checkbox'] => $item) {
     $data[] = unserialize($item);
}

var_dump($data);
exit;
```

Comment: Lo recorri con el foreach pero me imprime esto:    array(1) { [0]=> bool(false) }

Comment: bueno que tal si en lugar de serialize utilizas json_enconde() y luego para json_decode para obtenerlo por post?